# Replace text in Visual Studio Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

Recently I convert some of my old codes from `vb.net` to `C#`.

I need to change all my existing codes using visual studio regular expression (find & replace dialog inside Visual studio 2010 IDE)

Find

```
Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
```

Replace with

```
Rows[0][0].ToString()
```

that means

```
Rows(--any--).Item(--any--).ToString()
to 
Rows[--any--][--any--].ToString()
```

I searched a lot but  I am still  not able to do this.

Tip: I am using visual studio 2010

My old vb.net code is

```
Dim firstColumnValue As String = dataTable.Rows(0).Item("firstColumn")
Dim secondColumnValue As String = dataTable.Rows(0).Item("secondColumn")
```

When i am converting VB.net to C#, i got the following using [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc8da841-f978-4c3e-8397-c820bd57298c) plugin, i got this.

```
var firstColumnValue= dataTable.Rows(0).Item("firstColumn").ToString(); 
var secondColumnValue = dataTable.Rows(0).Item("SecondColumn").ToString();
```

But i actually wants like below.

```
var firstColumnValue= dataTable.Rows[0]["firstColumn"].ToString(); 
var secondColumnValue = dataTable.Rows[0]["SecondColumn"].ToString();
```

That vb.net to C# conversion tool converts almost all are fine but i need the above change in almost all files.

Comment: That doesn't mean that at all (unless I'm missing something), what is Rows? Items? What are you trying to achieve/do? (Note: Visual studio is just an IDE that has nothing to do with your code)

Comment: What? You don't write anything about regular expressions and I can't really understand what you want help with. Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh, do you want to search and replace in Visual Studio using regular expressions?

Comment: replace `(` with `[` and `)` with `]`. Is there any method to repalce characters in a string?

Comment: @kannan you mean this http://regex101.com/r/zM2pV9/2 ?

Comment: yes, avinash raj, you are right.  i want to use this inside visual studio find & search replace window

Comment: @kannan `.ToString();` in the replacement part is not necessary.

Comment: @kannan Is this must to use `{` before capturing group in VB?

Comment: Your code works & search my query fine, but when in replace it replace empty brackets (ex: Rows[][]), after including that { & } it works fine..

Comment: for your information i use C# not vb.net.

Comment: i added  c# code, it works without adding `{` in c#.

Comment: is it visual studio 2010 & .net framework 3.5?

Comment: is that the updated find and replace code correct?

Comment: ya. works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
Rows\(([^)]*)\)\.Item\(([^)]*)\)(\.ToString\(\))
```

**Replacement string:**

```
Rows[\1][\2]\3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zM2pV9/2)

**Example:**

```
string str = "foo bar Rows(0).Item(0).ToString() barfoo";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"Rows\(([^)]*)\)\.Item\(([^)]*)\)(\.ToString\(\))", "Rows[$1][$2]$3");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/3RWiKj)

Find:

```
Rows\({([^)]*)}\)\.Item\({([^)]*)}\)(\.ToString\(\))
```

Replace:

```
Rows[\1][\2]\3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

find : `Rows({\d*}).Item({\d*}).ToString()`

replace with :  `Rows[\1][\2].ToString()`

and check Use Regular Expression in the search/replace window

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Visual Studio to convert code from VB to C#.
You can use a free plug-ins like this one [This simple plug-in for Visual Studio 2010/2012 allows you to convert VB.net code to C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc8da841-f978-4c3e-8397-c820bd57298c)

Also this regex solutions below are not so perfect. For example: a function call inside parentheses, like `"foo bar Rows(0).Item(myfunc(n)).ToString() barfoo";`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was not perfect for function call inside parentheses, but i didn't have anything like " function call inside parentheses".